# how to get url segments count in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, url, segments

I have following Route,

```
http:/localhost/seg1/seg2/seg3
```

how to get `Request::segment` count from the url above ?

Expected result is,

```
$totalSegsCount = 3
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Request object has a function that returns [all segments](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_segments), place that in a `count()` to get the number you seek:

`$totalSegsCount = count(Request::segments());`